# react or npm issue: Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `...\react.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `react`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, es6-modules

I'm getting the following errors when I execute the `npm start` command on a react project.

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/react-scroll-pagination/dist/index.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `C:\Users\timhu\Dev\MongoDbStitch\PlateSpace\Web\node_modules\React\react.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `react`.

 @ ./~/react-scroll-pagination/dist/index.js 3:27-43

Error in ./~/react-scroll-pagination/dist/index.js
Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin] `C:\Users\timhu\Dev\MongoDbStitch\PlateSpace\Web\node_modules\jQuery\dist\jquery.js` does not match the corresponding path on disk `jquery`.

 @ ./~/react-scroll-pagination/dist/index.js 3:45-62
```

I'm new to react - but from what I can tell it's a pathing issue where `npm install` adds modules into the node_modules folder, all with lowercase folder names, but the compiler resolves to folder names with mixed case paths.

How do I fix this?   The code is from the [MongoDb Stitch PlateSpace tutorial project](https://github.com/mongodb/stitch-examples)

Do I updated the existing code (maybe the import statements) or is it a npm or react issue?

Thanks
Tim

Comment: From what console are you executing npm install?  I've found a difference between Powershell and Git bash (both on windows) for example.

Answer (score 13):

I come across the same problem.

I replaced :
`import React, {Component} from 'React'`, with :
`import React, {Component} from 'react'`.

React is case-sensitive, so be careful and good luck.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but in my case I had created a folder starting with a lowercase character, and every other folder that was inside of that folder was starting with a uppercase character. Changing the folder name to uppercase solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone facing this issue who is using `CRA`, I was getting this error and was not understanding why. My VS Code clearly showed the correctly named file, so I decided to check in the terminal:

`ls -la [path/to/file/location]`

I then actually saw that the file was in fact lowercase!

I renamed the file via the terminal and re-listed it to confirm:

```
mv src/create_page/createPage.jsx src/create_page/CreateDashboard.jsx
ls -la [path/to/file/location]
```

This fixed my issue, so at the end, I am not sure why this happened, maybe because my VS Code was not autosaving before I set the settings flag.

Comment: This is extremely basic, but restarting the server worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it...
I haven't import all the libraries. So, I went to my root folder and excecute.
    `npm install`
then
    `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

You may be executing the npm install / start inside of the wrong folder. I would delete the current directory and make sure to run the install in:

```
cd /stitch-examples/helloworld/react-example/
```

then

```
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's stated concern: `from what I can tell it's a pathing issue where npm install adds modules into the node_modules folder, all with lowercase folder names, but the compiler resolves to folder names with mixed case paths.`

Answer (score 0):

For this error :

> import React from 'react'; in your index.js file . For this error : Error in ./~/react-scroll-pagination/dist/index.js
>   Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin]C:\Users\timhu\Dev\MongoDbStitch\PlateSpace\Web\node_modules\jQuery\dist\jquery.jsdoes not match the corresponding path on diskjquery.

replace this code `import React from 'react';` in your index.js file .

For this error :

> Error in ./~/react-scroll-pagination/dist/index.js
>   Module not found: [CaseSensitivePathsPlugin]C:\Users\timhu\Dev\MongoDbStitch\PlateSpace\Web\node_modules\jQuery\dist\jquery.jsdoes not match the corresponding path on diskjquery.

replace the code with `import Jquery from './jquery'`;

Don't worry this errors will shows pretty commonly its because react is a case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the files on my disk was named `filename.js`, but my imports were doing this `import thing from 'fileName.js'`.

Renaming the file from `filename.js` to `fileName.js` on disk fixed the issue.